# laravel getting value request on function?

Tags: laravel

its very odd on my function, when i tried to get the data on the second `if` i got nothing

i just only got the last `if` whats the problem with code?

***controller.php**

```
public function viewType(Request $request){

    if($request->get('program') === 'reportall') {
        $reportviewall =  ReportViewAll::paginate(5);
    }
    if($request->get('program') === 'reportactive') {
        $reportviewall =  ReportViewAll::where('crewprogram_isdisabled', '=',0)->paginate(5);
    }
    if($request->get('program') === 'reporthistory') {
        $reportviewall =  ReportViewAll::where('crewprogram_isdisabled', '=',1)->paginate(5);
    }
    if(($request->get('datestart') && $request->get('dateend')) != ''){
        $reportviewall = ReportViewAll::whereDate('crewprogrammemo_placement_date', 
                        array($request->get('datestart'), $request->get('dateend')))->paginate(5);
    }
    if($request->has('search') != ''){
        $reportviewall = ReportViewAll::where( 'employee_nik', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )
                        ->orWhere ( 'employee_nama', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )
                        ->orWhere ( 'crewprogramposition_name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )
                        ->orWhere ( 'show_focus_id', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )
                        ->orWhere ( 'show_name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%" )->paginate(5);
    }
    // $reportviewall = $request->get('search')->paginate(5);
        // dd($request->search);
    return view('CrewProgram.ReportView.index', compact('reportviewall'));
}
```

please help meee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my mind on the last "if":
The "has" method returns true if the value is present on the request. Why are you expecting a string?

You may change that "if" to:

```
if($request->has('search') && $request->get('search') != '')
```

I don't know what you want to do, but maybe like this:

```
 if($request->has('search'))
```

Some tips for you:

But, I think you should refactor your code. Think about when you need to add new "if".
First of all, you should collect all the request data only once and put in a variable. Why are you replacing the '$reportviewall' variable all the time?

```
public function viewType(Request $request){
{
    $data = $request->only('program', 'datestart', 'dateend', 'search');

    // You need to create a new method
    $report = $this->chooseTheProgram($data['program']);

    if(!$report && !empty($data['datestart']) && !empty($data['dateend']))
    {
        // You need to create a new method
        $report = $this->retrieveBetween($data['datestart'], 
                                         $data['dateend']);
    } 
    else if (!$report && !empty($data['search']))
    {
         // You need to create a new method
         $report = $this->retrieveBy($data['search']);
    }

    return view('CrewProgram.ReportView.index', compact('report'));
}
```

Then, check if that the method is responsible for one more task. Try moving the code to the "model" layer.

[]'s

Comment: i tried using that u sugest but still not different, this is my edited code https://pastebin.com/4yNxSTzh, what i want to do that every reportviewall can be acccessed so when i click on program  it will give me the query builder that i want, and when it click date, will give me query builder that i want to, but in my code case, after i'm executing the program query builder, the rest query builder didn't affact or running. that's my problem

Comment: this is what i want @Alexandre Barbosa https://imgur.com/9fVW71B that's my pages looks like